# Making dictionaries for each sub folder

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, directory-structure

I want to make separate dictionaries for all sub folders in a main folder.

I have a folder with sub folders where there are .txt files of which I isolate the "Description" and add to a dictionary with a count.

I can get it right for the entire folder, but not separated per sub folder.

The sub folder structure is as follows:

```
├───Locatie_5
│   ├───Stacked_Batch_1
│   ├───Stacked_Batch_2_Top_Bottom
│   ├───Stacked_Loc5_Hab1_05mm
│   ├───Stacked_Loc5_Hab1_1mm
│   ├───Stacked_Loc5_Hab_General_Somesinglesmissingstill
│   └───Stacked_Loc_5_Hab2_Ishetwel5niet4
├───Stacked_Half_loc_4_Hab6_Half_loc_2_4
├───Stacked_Last_Session_Rest
├───Stacked_locatie_2_4
├───Stacked_Loc4_Hab6_25mm
└───Stacked_Locatie_2
```

The Desired output dictionaries should ideally be named after the folder (and if the case followed by the sub folder), list the Macro invertebrate taxon names found in the .txt files of the folders and the amount of times they occur as follows:

- Locatie_5_Stacked_Batch_1 = {"Anisus_vortex": "4", "Bithynia_tentaculata": "2", ...}
- Locatie_5_Stacked_Batch_2_Top_Bottom = {"Anisus_vortex": "7", "Bithynia_tentaculata": "3", ...}
- Stacked_Half_loc_4_Hab6_Half_loc_2_4 = {"Anisus_vortex": "0", "Bithynia_tentaculata": "25", ...}

  - etc...

**In the code below** getting all descriptions out of the main folder and its sub folders lumped into one dictionary is working. I thought it would be sensible to at least loop from the dirs in line 7 as a next step.
 It also would make sense to me to create the dictionaries in the loop and from there get the folder path as a string and assign it as the dictionary name.

So what I would like is the following:

- A dictionary for each sub folder
- In each dictionary the "Description" plus count from that sub folder
- Ideally the dictionary name should be- or include the sub folder name.

How do I go about this?

**A side note: I just need to get the descriptions and counts and know from which folders they come to place them into another file (.txt, a sheet or a database) eventually, so maybe there is a different solution than adding them to a dictionary first?**

```
import os
import re

taxa_Counts = dict()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("D:/MacroInvertebrates_Stacked"):
    for dir in dirs:
        for file in files:
            #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
            filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

            if not filepath.endswith(".txt"):
                continue

            Current_File = open(filepath)
            for line in Current_File:
                line = line.rstrip()
                #print(line)
                if line.startswith("Description"):
                    taxa = line.split()[2:3]

                    #print(line)
                    #print(Taxon)
                    for taxon in taxa:
                        taxa_Counts[taxon]=taxa_Counts.get(taxon,0) +1 

print(taxa_Counts)
```

Comment: Provide sample output you are expecting in order to avoid any ambiguity.There is a possible chance to nesting where there are sub folders inside sub folders. Present your subfolder structure using 'tree' command from terminal/cmd from the directory.

Comment: @RohithRNair Edited

Answer (score 0):

I have only made modification to the first part as your description extraction portion is working.

Please find the python 3 implementation below. I have not tried it, so please let me know if it is not working.

```
import os

root_folder = r'D:/MacroInvertebrates_Stacked'
content = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
    for subdir in dirs:
        content[os.path.join(root, subdir)] = []
    content[root] = files

list_of_dicts = []

for folder, filenames in list(content.items()):
    dict_name = string(os.path.relpath(folder, root_folder)).replace('\\', '_')
    dict_name = {}
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
           with open(filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    if line.startswith("Description"):
                        taxa = line.split()[2:3]
                        for taxon in taxa:
                            dict_name[taxon]=dict_name.get(taxon,0) +1 
    list_of_dicts.append(dict_name)

print(list_of_dicts)
```

list_of_dicts contains the dictionary names corresponding to each sub folder with the counts in it.